# Why my datatable won't show columns names?

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to use the datatable library but I must be missing something really basic cause i'm unable to show the columns:

This is my table:

```
<table 
  id="datatables" 
  class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover"
  cellspacing="0" style="width:100%"
>
</table>
```

This are my data sources:

```
const data = [
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "5421"
    },
    {
        "name":       "Garrett Winters",
        "position":   "Director",
        "salary":     "$5,300",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "8422"
    }
]

const columns =  [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' },
    { data: 'salary' },
    { data: 'office' }
]
```

and this is how I activate the table:

```
$('#datatables').DataTable({
    data,
    columns,
});
```

And this is the result:

[image]

why can't I see the name of the column? i'm doing it like in the example here:

https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Thanks in advance guys :(

Comment: You need a `<head>` section *or* define `title` in your `columns`-section. Where on earth do you imagine column names should come from, if not defined? :)

Comment: you're right, but in the example I can't see anything about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `columns.title` for that, see example [here](http://live.datatables.net/qacodapo/1/edit).

```
const columns =  [
    { data: 'name', title: 'name'},
    { data: 'position', title: 'position' },
    { data: 'salary', title: 'salary' },
    { data: 'office', title: 'office' }
]
```

Comment: right, I should read the docs more carefully. Thank you so much.